# Javascript Slideshow not sliding

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I am trying to make a slideshow from the book *Javascript in 24 Hours* from 2008. I think I have copied the code identically, yet the pictures shuffle, but they do not slide in as the book says they should. Does anyone mind taking the time to look this over?
Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Slideshow</title>
<style>
img.slide {
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>

<script>
// Slideshow
// Global variables
var numslides=0;
var currentslide=0,oldslide=4;
var x = 0;
var slides = new Array();
function MakeSlideShow() {
imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].className != "slide") continue;
    slides[numslides]=imgs[i];
    //Stack images with the first slide on top
    if (numslides==0) {
        imgs[i].style.zIndex=10;
    }
    else {
        imgs[i].style.zIndex=0;
    }
    imgs[i].onclick=NextSlide;
    numslides++;
} // end for loop
}// end MakeSlideShow

function NextSlide() {
//Set the current slide to be under the new top slide
slides[currentslide].style.zIndex=9;
// Move older slide to the bottom of the stack
slides[oldslide].style.zIndex=0;
oldslide = currentslide;
currentslide++;
if (currentslide >= numslides) currentslide = 0;
// Start at the right edge
slides[currentslide].style.left=400;
x=400;
//Move the new slide to the top
slides[currentslide].style.zIndex=10;
AnimateSlide();
}

function AnimateSlide() {
// Lower moves slower, higher moves faster
x = x - 25;
slides[currentslide].style.left=x;
//Previous image moves off the left edge
slides[oldslide].style.left=x-400;
//Repeat until until the slide is at the zero position
if (x > 0) window.setTimeout("AnimateSlide();",10);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MakeSlideShow();">
            <div id = "slideshow">
                <img class = "slide" src = "pic1.jpg" width = "400px" height = "400px" >
                <img class = "slide" src = "pic2.jpg" width = "400px" height = "400px" >
                <img class = "slide" src = "pic3.jpg" width = "400px" height = "400px" >
                <img class = "slide" src = "pic4.jpg" width = "400px" height = "400px" >
                <img class = "slide" src = "pic5.jpg" width = "400px" height = "400px" >
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FWIW, 2008 is getting pretty ancient these days.

Comment: Your script works fine, check here http://jsfiddle.net/Jvkcc/3/

Comment: Here is what you posted, btw, using HTML5 instead and with the `body onload` under the `info` tab: http://jsfiddle.net/rXkVG/ There's an error in the console.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran - Chrome latest.

Comment: I checked on Chrome and IE,  it's working fine for me.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran - I'm getting `Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.` and nothing happens. Still investigating.

Comment: @Jared - You might have blocked JS ,look in the address bar right side you might be getting some items blocked, unblocking will resolve your problem, That script runs fine NO problem with source code

Comment: check to make sure that you have the same version of jquery as the book is using.

Comment: @defau1t - It's not using any jQuery, it's regular plain ol' Javascript. Ameya Rote, it's probably a red herring, I agree. Still looking at it, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I think xml declaration at the head is causing the error.

Comment: David, here's a simplified version (minus the `AnimateSlide` function): http://jsfiddle.net/rXkVG/6/ (Do note, for simplicity, I omit testing for `attachEvent`, which IE =< 8 supports instead of `addEventListener`. The latter works in all other browsers, plus IE9.)

Comment: A bit simpler (still no animate, but less code for the setup and `NextSlide`): http://jsfiddle.net/rXkVG/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Your script is very fine ...

The problem is in two lines of this function

```
    function AnimateSlide() {
    ...
    ...
    slides[currentslide].style.left=x;
    slides[oldslide].style.left=x-400;
    ...
    }
```

Modification is that left value should have "px". So Modified Lines are

```
slides[currentslide].style.left=x +"px";
slides[oldslide].style.left=x-400 +"px";
```

Now it is sliding. jsfiddle Demo path is http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/Jvkcc/5/

Comment: Great! I previously tried adding px at the end of 400 (400px), because I had a feeling this is where the problem was, but that obviously doesn't work. It makes sense that px needs to be appended as a string. Thanks a million+

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have embedded your html code inside an XML document. if you get rid of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top of the page, it should get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It works, it slides to the next image on click of the current image. Line 40 in your code,

```
imgs[i].onclick=NextSlide;
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of the simple slideshow:

http://jsfiddle.net/rXkVG/11/

(A [slightly more clever example](http://jsfiddle.net/rXkVG/12/).)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load() {
    var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow'),
        imgs = slideshow.getElementsByTagName("img"),
        offset = 178,
        speed = 25,
        step = 10,
        animated = false,
        slides = [];

    SetupSlideShow();

    function SetupSlideShow() {
        var items = imgs.length,
            next = items,
            slide;

        while (next--) {
            slide = imgs[next];

            if (slide.className.indexOf("slide") != -1) {
                slides.push(slide);

                slide.style.zIndex = items - next;

                slide.addEventListener('click', Change);
            }
        }
    }

    function Change() {
        if (animated) {
            return;
        }

        Animate();
    }

    function Animate() {
        var slide = slides[slides.length - 1],
            left = 0;

        animated = true;

        slideshow.style.cursor = 'wait';
        slide.style.left = left;

        (function animate() {
            left = left - step;

            if (left > offset * -1) {
                slide.style.left = left + 'px';

                setTimeout(animate, 25);
            } else {
                animated = false;

                slideshow.style.cursor = 'pointer';

                Next();
            }
        })();
    }

    function Next() {
        var slide = slides.length;

        slides.unshift(slides.pop());

        while (slide--) {
            slides[slide].style.zIndex = slide;
            slides[slide].style.left = 0;
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Your demo would be complete if you Make bottom images clickable